# Run service after succesfull connected to internet because of updating data for widgets

Tags: android, service, internet-connection

Is there any better idea how to check if my device is connected to the internet? Or is the only solution use alarm manager or something like that, that checks with the method checking internet connection periodically. But my application is not running, because I need it for updating data for widgets. So my question is: Is there something, that gets response from some java class of android that yes, I am already connected to the internet? Its pretty tough to ask it my words, i hope, you understand me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public boolean IsConnected() {
    final ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final NetworkInfo activeNetwork = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but i know this method already. I meant some smart method, that will check no in my application, when i haven't some running activity.

Comment: I believe you are looking for Service: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Comment: Yeah, i know about it, but does it drains a lot of battery? Of course, i know, that it depends on the structure of the code and methods, but still, does it?

Comment: It is relative of course, but IMO it will not have a big impact (assuming you don't check every 1ms :))